# How to keep calling a url in jQuery until you get the result that's expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jenkins

I have a jQuery script in which I am making a call to a Jenkins web server that kicks off a build.  This build takes n amount of time to finish, which I have no way of knowing.  In Jenkins, you can find out if a build is done by looking at the JSON API for that build.  Here you can look for key value "building" and if false you know the build is done.  I check this object 12 secs after making the initial call.  This 12 secs is a best guess estimate which I don't want to rely on.

So I thought about putting my query in a while loop and continuously checking the JSON object until "building" evaluates to false.  But this is causing my browser to crash cause it's too much.

Is there someway other than doing a setTimeout to do this?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:
        "jenkins url that calls build",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },  
    complete: function () {
    },  
    success: function () {
        /** Give build 12 secs to finish. **/
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:
                    "json url that stores the results of build",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function () {
                },  
                complete: function () {
                },  
                success: function (lastBuild) {  
                }   
            }); 
        }, 12000);
    }   
});
```

With while loop

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:
        "jenkins url that calls build",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },  
    complete: function () {
    },  
    success: function () {
        var building = false;
        // Freaks out here.
        while (!building) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:
                    "json url that stores the results of build",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function () {
                },  
                complete: function () {
                },  
                success: function (lastBuild) {
                    building = lastBuild["building"];
                }   
            });
        }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion function, and it is called within success function.

```
var building=false;
function callFunction()
{   jQuery.ajax({
        url:
           "json url that stores the results of build",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },  
        complete: function () {
        },  
        success: function (lastBuild) {
           building=lastBuild["building"];
           if(building!=true) callFunction();
        }   
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I think you meant if (building) callFunction();

Comment: Also, this pops the next Ajax off immediately.  You may (or may not) want to give the server a chance to "breath" by using if (building) setTimeout(callFunction, 1000); instead of if (building) callFunction();

Comment: Finally (I think), you don't need to declare var building = false; outside the success function. Just use var building = lastBuild["building"];